# element doesn't appear when display it block after a response jquery laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

**I'm trying to save data (id), which retrieved from database and stored in a button, it appears in a (modal) like that:**

[image]

there is a button (Add) and a another button (Remove) but it's hidden.
**what I want to do is:**

_when user press (Add) button the (id) which, stored inside this button (Add), go to controller, which stored this (id) into a session like That:

```
public function sotreInSession(Request $request)
{
    session()->push('card.contactId',$request->contactId);
    return response()->json([
        'status' => true,
        'msg' => 'added successfully',
    ]);
}
```

**then button (Add) become hidden, and button (remove) become visible.**

- the (id) stored successfully and the response is completed **but the issue is:**
- the button (remove) doesn't appear!.
- button (Add) doesn't become hidden although, the logic is right.

**Routes:**

```
    ############### Contacts ####################

Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth:web'], function(){
    Route::post('/contact-store', [ContactController::class,'sotreInSession'])->name('site.contacts.sotreInSession');
    Route::get('/contact-remove', [ContactController::class,'removeFromSession'])->name('site.contacts.removeFromSession');
});

############### End Contacts ####################
```

**Controller:**

```
    public function sotreInSession(Request $request)
{
    session()->push('card.contactId',$request->contactId);
    return response()->json([
        'status' => true,
        'msg' => 'added successfully',
    ]);
}
```

**Blade page and script:**

```
   <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row  d-flex justify-content-center " style="font: normal normal bold 24px/45px Cairo; color: #0D67CB">
        <p class="text-center">New Card</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row pl-3 pr-3 mr-3 ml-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <form id="addCardForm">
            @csrf
            <input type="text" name="cardName" class="form-control" placeholder="Card Name">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="row pt-5 d-flex justify-content-center" style="font: normal normal bold 18px/33px Cairo; color: #171717;">
        <p class="text-center">Add a Verified Contact to your Card</p>
    </div>
    @if(isset($contacts) && $contacts->count()>0)
        @foreach($contacts as $contact)
            <div class="row pt-5 d-flex justify-content-center align-content-center">
                <a href=""><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" fill="#3C5A9A" class="bi bi-facebook" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M16 8.049c0-4.446-3.582-8.05-8-8.05C3.58 0-.002 3.603-.002 8.05c0 4.017 2.926 7.347 6.75 7.951v-5.625h-2.03V8.05H6.75V6.275c0-2.017 1.195-3.131 3.022-3.131.876 0 1.791.157 1.791.157v1.98h-1.009c-.993 0-1.303.621-1.303 1.258v1.51h2.218l-.354 2.326H9.25V16c3.824-.604 6.75-3.934 6.75-7.951z"/>
                    </svg></a>
                <p class="pl-5 pt-2 pr-5">{{$contact->contact_string}}</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" data-id="{{$contact->id}}" id="addContactToCard">Add</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm d-none" data-id="{{$contact->id}}" id="removeContactFromCard">Remove</button>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    @else
        <div class="row pt-5 d-flex justify-content-center align-content-center">
            <p class="pl-5 pt-2 pr-5">You have no contacts add at least one contact</p>
        </div>
    @endif
</div>
<div class="modal-footer pr-5 pt-5 pb-5">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Reset</button>
    <button type="button" id="saveCard" class="btn btn-warning">Save Card</button>
</div>


<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#addContactToCard', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var contactId = $(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "{{route('site.contacts.sotreInSession')}}",
            data: {
                contactId:contactId,
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function (response){
                if(response===true){
                    $(this).css("display", "none");
                    $('#removeContactFromCard').css("display", "block");
                }
            }, error: function (reject){

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

any help in this issue or any better solution for this case?

Answer (score 0):

Try

**Change:**

```
if(response===true){
     $(this).css("display", "none");
     $('#removeContactFromCard').css("display", "block");
}
```

**To:**

```
if(response.status==true){
    $(e.target).addClass('d-none');
    $(e.target).next('#removeContactFromCard').removeClass('d-none');
}
```

Comment: it's supposed (response.status) right, i changed it but the button  doesn't hide, i Think that i can't hide the button  by the button itself right?

Comment: you cant use `$(this)` try `$('#addContactToCard').hide();`

Comment: Thanks it works and disappear, but there are some issues, button (remove) doesn't appear, the others buttons (add) have the same (id) and i can't change it cuz these data comes from database the only unique attribute for every button is (data-id).

Comment: Try to get the selected (add) button from the event, and then select each (remove) button next to it. as the answer updated.

Comment: Thanks for your care I've tried (e.target) as you update, button (add) disappears and the other works fine, but  button (remove) doesn't appear, I think the better solution to change these button and replace it by (check box), in this case  i can store the (chekboxes value)  better than this approach